# mysql_store_result not recognized as a function in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had a database class using the mysqli connectors which is working fine, i want to change that to use  mysql but

```
mysql_store_result,
mysql_more_results, 
mysql_next_result, 
mysql_multi_query
```

are not recognized as functions

What should I do?

Comment: why are you going backwards?

Comment: That's probably because those functions don't exist in PHP. What you should do is stick with MySQLi

Comment: Drew I am hosting it on a hold server which complains about mysqli

Comment: *"Complains about mysqli*", what? You sure it's not giving you notices about `mysql_` being deprecated?

Comment: Then I would host it on a server that you don't complain about. Ie: modern stuff

Comment: The `mysql` extension has never supported multiple queries. If you really need to do this, you'll need to recode everything to use separate queries.

Comment: `mysqli` is fine. What's the motivation behind using these outdated and no longer supported methods? After years of causing untold suffering and misery they were deleted in PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

What should you do? Find or setup a server that supports the `mysqli_` interface functions.

Abandon attempts to rewrite code using `mysqli_` to backport it to `mysql_`. Move *forwards*, not *backwards*.

Comment: @tadman: arguably PDO would be a better option. OP reports "already using mysqli connectors which is working fine". So I only addressed that. (I thought PDO and mysqli were both introduced way back in PHP 5.0, at the same time, so I was thinking a PHP server that's not supporting mysqli would also not support PDO. I could certainly be wrong about that. I think finally dropping the `mysql_` interface functions was *way* overdue.